# Incorporating pagination scraping into my script

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

```
url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=electronics"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

names = soup.find_all("div", class_="s-item__title")

prices = soup.find_all("span", class_="s-item__price")

shippings = soup.find_all("span", class_="s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost"


for name,price,shipping in zip(names,prices,shippings):
    print(name.text, price.text, shipping.text)
```

Right now, this script works perfectly. It prints everything that needs to be printed.
But... I want to be able to go to the next page and scrape everything off of there as well.
The class for the next page is "pagination__next icon-link"
I'm not sure how I would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate link by pagination url query value

```
base_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=electronics&_pgn='
for i in range(pages_count):
    base_url+f'{i}'

    # your code...
    response = requests.get(url)
```

For correct parsing by category, due to the specifics of the displayed pages of the site, I advise you to refer to the pagination object for each request, look at the last page number and substitute it in the request

Take last number of available page on current page:

```
ol = soup.find("ol", class_="pagination__items")
lis = ol.find_all("li")

print(f"Last available number of post on current page {lis[-1].text}")
```

Comment: yes but what about using soup.select_one to click the "next page" icon?

Comment: for what? you also need to parse all pages for a given url. Make an while loop with a counter and a boolean status. If the last page is the same for 2 pages in a row, then change the status to false and finish the remaining pages.

Comment: bs4 is not selenium, bs4 is a scraper, it cannot emit clicks (unlike selenium). Therefore, you need to iterate all pages by url and update the last page every time and check whether it is the last or not (this is specifically for ebay, where pagination does not give the last page number)

Comment: I can't give feedback but when I can I will definitely.

Answer (score 0):

In order to collect all the information from all pages, you can use the `while` loop which dynamically paginates through all pages.

The while loop will be executed until there is a stop command, in our case, the command to end the loop will be to check for the presence of the next page, for which the CSS selector is responsible - ".pagination__next".

Also, there's a [URL parameter](https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/) that is responsible for pagination: [`_pgn`](https://serpapi.com/ebay-search-api#api-parameters-pagination--pgn) which is used to  increase page number by 1 and thus selects the next page:

```py
if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
else:
     break
```

See the full code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-ebay-using-pagination-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
  }
    
params = {
    "_nkw": "electronics",   # search query  
    "_pgn": 1                # page number
  }

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    print("-" * 10)
    
    for products in soup.select(".s-item__info"):
        title = products.select_one(".s-item__title span").text
        price = products.select_one(".s-item__price").text
        link = products.select_one(".s-item__link")["href"]
        
        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Nintendo DSi XL Japan Import Console & USB Charger - Pick Your Color TESTED",
    "price": "$69.99",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/165773301243?hash=item2698dbd5fb:g:HFcAAOSwTdNhnqy~&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4MXRmWPDY6vBlTlYLy%2BEQPsi1HJM%2BFzt2TWJ%2BjCbK6Q2mreLV7ZpKmZOvU%2FMGqxY2oQZ91aPaHW%2FS%2BRCUW3zUKWDIDoN2ITF3ooZptkWCkd8x%2FIOIaR7t2rSYDHwQEFUD7N6wdnY%2Bh6SpljeSkCPkoKi%2FDCpU0YLOO3mpuLVjgO8GQYKhrlXG59BDDw8IyaayjRVdWyjh534fuIRToSqFrki97dJMVXE0LNE%2BtPmJN96WbYIlqmo4%2B278nkNigJHI8djvwHMmqYUBQhQLN2ScD%2FLnApPlMJXirqegMet0DZQ%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7K0tsSSYQ"
  },
  {
    "title": "Anbernic RG351P White, Samsung 64 GB SD Card AmberElec & Case",
    "price": "$89.99",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/144690079314?hash=item21b0336652:g:8qwAAOSw93ZjO6n~&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoNGQWvtymUdp2cEYaKyfTAzWm0oZvBODZsm2oeHl3s%2F6jF9k3nAIpsQkpiZBFI657Cg53X9zAgExAxQAfmev0Bgh7%2FjEtC5FU8O5%2FfoQ3tp8XYtyKdoRy%2FwdebmsGKD%2FIKvW1lWzCNN%2FpSAUDLrPgPN9%2Fs8igeU7jqAT4NFn3FU7W4%2BoFV%2B2gNOj8nhxYlm3HZ6vm21T4P3IAA4KXJZhW2E%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7K0tsSSYQ"
  },
  {
    "title": "New ListingWhite wii console ONLY Tested Working",
    "price": "$24.99",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/385243730852?hash=item59b250d3a4:g:t3YAAOSwZBBjctqi&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoH9I%2BSQlJpKebgObGE7Idppe2cewzEiV0SdZ6pEu0sVpIJK5%2F3q15ygTFAdPRElY232LwDKIMXjkIwag1FUN76geBg2vCnPfd3x8BAHzXn%2B1u5zF9cBITLCuawKTYnfUeCYMavO4cBmpnsrvUOSokvnTacfB078MF95%2FH1sUQH%2BfIjDtPzFoFTJrTtKLINRlXZ9edD%2BVW%2FB2TLYZ%2FHMAHkE%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7K0tsSSYQ"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code that paginates through all pages:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
from urllib.parse import (parse_qsl, urlsplit)
import os, json

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),      # serpapi api key    
    "engine": "ebay",                     # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",            # ebay domain
    "_nkw": "electronics",                # search query 
}

search = EbaySearch(params)        # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        link = organic_result.get("link")
        price = organic_result.get("price")

        data.append({
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })
                    
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    next_page_query_dict = dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results["serpapi_pagination"]["next"]).query)) 
    current_page = results["serpapi_pagination"]["current"] # 1,2,3...

    # looks for the next page data (_pgn):
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
        
        # if current_page = 20 and next_page_query_dict["_pgn"] = 20: break
        if int(current_page) == int(next_page_query_dict["_pgn"]):
            break
        
        # update next page data
        search.params_dict.update(next_page_query_dict)
    else:
        break
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$169.00",
      "extracted": 169.0
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/113356737439?hash=item1a64968b9f:g:4qoAAOSwQypdKgT6&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4N8GJRRCbG8WIU7%2BzjrvsRMMmKaTEnA0l7Nz9nOWUUSin3gZ5Ho41Fc4A2%2FFLtlLzbb5UuTtU5s3Qo7Ky%2FWB%2FTEuDKBhFldxMZUzVoixZXII6T1CTtgG5YFJWs0Zj8QldjdM9PwBFuiLNJbsRzG38k7v1rJdg4QGzVUOauPxH0kiANtefqiBhnYHWZ0RfMqwh4S%2BbQ59JYQWSZjAefL61WYyNwkfSdrfcq%2BW2B7b%2BR8QEfynka5CE6g7YPpoWWp4Bk3IOvd4CZxAzTpgvOPoMMKPy0VCW1gPJDG4R2CsfDEv%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR56IpsWSYQ"
  },
  {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$239.00",
      "extracted": 239.0
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/115600879000?hash=item1aea596d98:g:F3YAAOSwsXxjbuYn&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4LuAhrdA4ahkT85Gf15%2FtEH9GBe%2B0qlDZfEt4p9O0YPmJZVPyq%2Fkuz%2FV86SF3%2B7SYY%2BlK04XQtCyS3NGyNi03GurFWx2dYwoKFUj2G7YsLw%2BalUKmdiv5bC3jJaRTnXuBOJGPXQxw2IwTHcvZ%2Fu8T7tEnYF5ih3HGMg69vCVZdVHqRa%2FYehvk14wVwj3OwBTVrNM8dq7keGeoLKUdYDHCMAH6Y4je4mTR6PX4pWFS6S7lJ8Zrk5YhyHQInwWYXwkclgaWadC4%2BLwOzUjcKepXl5mDnxUXe6pPcccYL3u8g4O%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR56IpsWSYQ"
  },
  # ...
]
```